# Trouble entering session variables into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

So I'm trying to input some session variables into the database, and I'm successfuly inserting all rows, except the $_SESSION['organisationId']. Some context: A user lands on a url as the one given in the snippit below, I get the organisationId, then want that user to be assigned that organisationId when they create the account - working as a sort of 'invite-system' of sorts.

// This is the URL I am using: http://thisapp.com/login.php?competitionId=51da7ed4d686a&organisationId=51d81cab92709

```
   <?php
      session_start();
      ob_start();
      ini_set('display_errors',1);
      ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
      error_reporting(-1);

       include('db.php');

    $_SESSION['competitionId'] = $_GET['competitionId'];
    $_SESSION['organisationId'] = $_GET['organisationId'];

    <h4>Create your Account</h4>

    <form action="login.php" method="post" name="acceptinvite">
        name: <input type="text" name="createname"><br>
        email: <input type="text" name="createemail"><br>
        password: <input type="password" name="createpassword"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
    </form>

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST["createname"]) && !empty($_POST["createname"])) {

        //define variables
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['createname']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['createemail']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['createpassword']);
        $teamLeader = 0;
        $organisationId = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['organisationId']);
        $orgName = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['orgName']);

        //finish registering the user
        $acceptInviteTeam = ("INSERT INTO `users` (`organisationId`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `isTeamLeader`) VALUES ('$organisationId', '$name', '$email', '$password', '$teamLeader')");
        $result = mysql_query($acceptInviteTeam)  or die (mysql_error());
    }

    else {
        echo "Fill out the form and use the correct credentials";
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: what is the data type of the organisationId? I see letters in it

Comment: uniqid(); & in the db (varchar 255 latin1)

Comment: echo $organisationId right before '$acceptInviteTeam = ...' and see what you get

Comment: Nothing - blank. if I submit the form and echo the query, I get this: INSERT INTO `users` (`organisationId`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `isTeamLeader`) VALUES ('', 'aasd', 'asda', 'asdad', '0')

Comment: Well there you go. Now you have to echo organisationId before you escape it and organisationId in $_GET and see where the problem is originating from

Comment: I can echo it out successfully by Get, then echoing out the session variable. So it is from within the "if" statement it is failing.

Comment: Hey one thing. What is '<h4>Create your Account</h4>' doing there??? try echoing it, or close the php tag before it and open it again after it. Who knows maybe this is the problem. You haven't closed the php tag before it

Comment: sorry, that tag got lost somewhere whilst pasting in here,  it is closed in my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the problem is.
When you enter the link http://thisapp.com/login.php?competitionId=51da7ed4d686a&organisationId=51d81cab92709 you have organisationId and you save it in the session. But the target of the form is simply login.php. when you submit the form, there is no organisationId in the url, so the session variable gets overwritten by null.
This is the fix:

```
$_SESSION['competitionId'] = isset($_GET['competitionId']) ? $_GET['competitionId'] : $_SESSION['competitionId'];
$_SESSION['organisationId'] = isset($_GET['organisationId']) ? $_GET['organisationId'] : $_SESSION['organisationId'];
```

Alternatively you can use an if statement.